# using variables in attributes using xpath & scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

i need some help trying to figure out how to use variables in xpath attributes when using the scrapy framework

eg hxs.select('/tr[@name="tag_1"]/td/text()').extract()

but there are 100 tags  so tag_1, tag_2, tag_3 etc
im trying to loop through it but scrapy is erroring on me
im using @name="tag_" + x
where x is the loop variable but its not working
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that may be just a problem with badly placed quotes, try something like:

```
for x in range(100):
    str_selector = '/tr[@name="tag_{0}"]/td/text()'.format(x)
    hxs.select(str_selector)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The loop works but I cant seem to get scrapy to return the individual items. It seems to only scrap the first one over and over.  If use print str_selector within the loop i can see it produce different values but scrapy only seems to save the first one.

Comment: could you show a snippet of your html where those tr elements are?

Comment: I have since discovered I need to put the item = scrapyItem() within the loop and not outside of it. Thanks for your help.